# problem with dagger 2 android(java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError)

Tags: static, dagger-2

I'm trying to use Dagger 2 , i don't know why i get error , but i think it is for static method in my App class !

main class

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

     @Inject
     public Picasso picasso;

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         App.getComponent().injector(this);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         ButterKnife.bind(this);
     }
```

App class(G) 
maybe the problem is in this class :

```
public class App extends Application {

    static ApplicationComponent component;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

      component = DaggerApplicationComponent.builder()
                .picassoModule(new PicassoModule(this))
                .build();
    }
    public static ApplicationComponent getComponent() {
        return component;
    }

}
```

my component interface code is :

```
@Component(modules = PicassoModule.class)
public interface ApplicationComponent {

    void injector(MainActivity mainActivity);
}
```

my module class

```
@Module
public class PicassoModule {

    private Context context;

    public PicassoModule(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }
    @Provides
    public Picasso picasso(){
        return new  Picasso.Builder(context)
                .build();
    }

}
```

[image: Error screen]

Comment: Please don't post error logs using image, copy paste it in a code block

Comment: Added image to question

Answer (score 0):

From the screenshot there is an error from OkHttp which says expected API 21+ but was 19.

So probably Dagger is not the culprit here